# PHP Code: Trying to link to a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP file which is designed to link to a test SQL table which I've set up. The problem is that entering data into my search box isn't getting the results I'm after.

First, the PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM 'create'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["FirstName"]. " " . $row["LastName"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And the SQL file, copied and pasted from the CSV version, in order of ID, FirstName, LastName...

```
1,"Ryan","Butler"
2,"Ryan","Butler"
3,"Brent","Callahan"
4,"Harry","Callahan","makemyday@dirtyharry.net"
5,"Luke","Cage","luke@mywifeisdead.com",
6,"Jessica","Jones","jessica@getkilgrave.org",
```

The result of entering any of the above words in my search box should give me a result of 6. Jessica. Jones. (I'm not bothering to search for the emails, I don't know why I included them.) Instead, I get "0 results" no matter what I type.

There's probably just one thing that I have wrong, but I'll be damned if I know what it is. Then again, PHP is not my forté.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have helped you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table name should be in backticks, not quotes.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM `create`";
```

Comment: Ooh, that did it. Thank you!

Comment: And with respect to mysqli.error.php, I'm such a novice that I don't think it would've helped me. Thanks, though.