# Getting Single Results From SQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

First I am grateful for the help I received with [my question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818711/php-code-trying-to-link-to-a-mysql-table), but there's still something I haven't quite figured out.

When I enter a word or term in my search box, to be handled by the code below...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {    
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) { 
  // output data of each row
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["FirstName"]. " " . $row["LastName"]. "<br>"; 
    } 
} else { 
echo "0 results"; 
} 

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I get all the possible results listed from my SQL table.

So, how do I limit the results to those the end user has entered? I know that I should use either a LIKE or WHERE statement.

If it helps, I am creating a database of medical professionals, their practice names, and locations.

Comment: Explain thw inputs. Means result match against firstname ????

Comment: @devpro -- either firstname or lastname. 'ID' doesn't really need to be there, I suppose.

Comment: Chk answer it will work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Search: <input name="search" type="text">
</form>
```

You could extend your SQL as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM `table` ";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
    $sql .= " WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$search%'
                 OR LastName LIKE '%$search%' ";
}
$sql .= " LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// ... etc.
```

To be clear, the *"... etc."* means that your outputting code remains as-is:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) { 
    // output data of each row
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["FirstName"]. " " . $row["LastName"]. "<br>"; 
    } 
} else { 
    echo "0 results"; 
} 

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Plz remove ending $ %$search$%

Comment: I substituted the code by @trincot for lines 15-21, and now I can't get onto my PHP page after all. (I didn't change anything else.)

Comment: @BionicBundtcake, please explain what you mean with *I can't get onto my PHP page"*? Note that you should only replace 2 of your original lines with the code above: in fact only the line `$sql = ` should be replaced by my code, but I repeated your `$result = ...` to make clear where your code remains as it is.

Comment: I mean that instead of getting "0 results," I now get a blank page, on which I can't even view the code.

Comment: Sorry, here's what it looks like after line 14:

`code`   $sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM `create` ";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
    $sql .= " WHERE FirstName LIKE '$%search%' OR LastName LIKE '$%search%' ";

$sql .= "LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

} else { 
  echo "0 results"; 
} 

mysqli_close($conn);
?> `code`

Comment: Well, you removed all code that outputs the result. I did not say to remove that. Please read my answer again: **extend** the SQL code. I never wrote to remove the code you already had to output the results.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql1=mysqli_query("SELECT*FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$result1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
```

Comment: Plz add explanation and what r u doing mixing mysql and mysqli??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.